# Local file system access

Tags: node.js, azure

If I have an Azure Nodejs site, what sort of access to the file system do I have? Can my app rely on files within its directory to continually exist? Or will Azure wipe and re-deploy my app behind the scenes?

The reason I'm asking is that I'd like to use sqlite to have a lightweight persistence capability for my app. Using an Azure service would probably be overkill for my use case.

I looked around for docs on this but couldn't find a good answer.

Comment: Are you asking about Web Apps? Cloud Services (web / worker roles)? Virtual Machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can persist the sqlite data file in your app directory. by default, your application will be deployed to `d:/home/site/wwwroot` on Azure Web Apps, and as the [link](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment#persisted-files) @Alex provided shows that, you can persist the files in this path. Azure will not wipe any files in this path unless you do any changes.

And BTW, the space of Azure Web Apps have limitation:

> Free and Shared sites get 1GB of space, Basic sites get 10GB, and Standard sites get 50GB. See more details on the [Web App Pricing](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/) page.

You should watch out the your whole application's size.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your file system access is limited to your root web app folder. Regarding your concrete question - no, it should not wipe your files that are stored in your storge.

More information is [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment) - Kudu is a nice tooling to make different things done with your web app. From Kudu console (http://webappname.SCM.azurewebsites.net, note SCM) you may even access the storage area you have access to.

Comment: Are you sure this would work for a sqllite database?  When the role recycles for whatever reason, the code from Azure storage will be dropped as it was when deployed, It won't keep/persist the changes, will it?